# Water Release Valve that doesn't look like a Pressure Release Valve

Tags: water

This "valve" started spewing water this AM and the only way to stop it was to turn off the main water and then turn it back on.   Any idea what this is and what would've happened if we weren't home?  Would it have reset on it's own?

[image: valve]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where is this valve in your house, and what's on the other side of that wall? (A picture of the other side would be great.) And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is one of your systems over-pressure? and that is its safety valve?

Comment: This is located outside the house next to the main line in from the street. I believe it is some type of safety valve that my irrigation system triggered today but I am not sure.   The other side of the wall is the garage but there is nothing visible in the garage so it is plumbed internally.  The water heater is in the garage.  The home is in Florida and I am from Chicago and the valves we had there were a bell shaped PRV.  My concerns are 1) What triggers this valve  2) Will it reset w/o shutting off the main then opening it again

Answer (score 2):

That looks EXACTLY like a pressure (only) release valve (as opposed to a pressure/temperature release valve.) I have one that looks like it on the inlet of my water system, though I do have an extender pipe to take the water nearer the floor attached to it.

As far as I recall (I tested when I installed it, but that's a few years ago now), mine resets on its own when the pressure is reduced below its threshold (it's just a spring seal) so I would guess that whatever  caused the part of the system that is being protected by this valve to be over-pressure was stuck there until you turned off the main valve. Identifying what that was and fixing it so it does not stick open would be my best guess on not having this happen again, but it might not be easy unless you have a pretty good idea of what it was (you suspect the irrigation system, presumably for some reason.)

Comment: I have installed similar , once the pressure drops on the inlet side the valve will usually close on its own, if it has not cycled for a long time it may stick open until the water pressure is well below the trip point.+

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is related to the irrigation system as this happened during the morning run today.  I found a valve on an irrigation system web site that looks identical so I believe I answered my own question :)   I will replace the valve and examine my irrigation system to see if something could be creating an over-pressure situation.   Thanks!

http://www.irrigationoutlet.com/valves-and-accessories/valves-and-accessories-pressure-relief-valves/valves-and-accessories-pressure-relief-valves-bob

Comment: Does your irrigation system have an anti-backflow valve ? Could this valve be part of a system to prevent water from the irrigation lines flowing back into the potable water supply lines? Or is this simply a pressure relief valve designed to prevent damage by limiting the pressure to 75 psi? What does your water supplier state about the pressure supplied to their residential customers? Is the pressure high enough that customers must have a pressure reducing valve at the entrance to their lines?